# python scrape using requests failing to be able to parse the json

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, jq

I have a python3 program which hits an API with an API Token Key but fails to get the data

The run:

./mumble.py.exp

```
{'last': 313.14, 'bidPrice': None, 'quoteTimestamp': '2020-05-19T20:00:00+00:00', 'mid': None, 'open': 315.03, 'timestamp': '2020-05-19T20:00:00+00:00', 'tngoLast': 313.14, 'lastSize': None, 'askSiz\
e': None, 'ticker': 'AAPL', 'askPrice': None, 'low': 313.01, 'volume': 25189979, 'prevClose': 314.96, 'bidSize': None, 'lastSaleTimestamp': '2020-05-19T20:00:00+00:00', 'high': 318.52}
```

The code:

```
~/mumble$ cat mumble.py.exp

#!/usr/bin/python3

import requests
import json

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

requestResponse = requests.get("https://api.foobar.com/iex/?tickers=aapl&token=APITOKENKEY", headers=headers)

output = requestResponse.json()

print(output[0])
```

Attempt to parse with jq:

./mumble.py.exp | jq "."

parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 8

I'd like to look at the last field in the Python and not have to try to work it through jq but I don't know how to do it.

Anyone know how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
dictionary = {'last': 313.14, 'bidPrice': None, 'quoteTimestamp': '2020-05-19T20:00:00+00:00', 'mid': None, 'open': 315.03, 'timestamp': '2020-05-19T20:00:00+00:00', 'tngoLast': 313.14, 'lastSize': None, 'askSiz\
e': None, 'ticker': 'AAPL', 'askPrice': None, 'low': 313.01, 'volume': 25189979, 'prevClose': 314.96, 'bidSize': None, 'lastSaleTimestamp': '2020-05-19T20:00:00+00:00', 'high': 318.52}

#print(dictionary['last'])
for i in dictionary:
    print(dictionary['last'])
    print(dictionary['bidPrice'])
    print(dictionary['quoteTimestamp'])
    print(dictionary['mid'])
    print(dictionary['open'])
    print(dictionary['timestamp'])
    print(dictionary['tngoLast'])
    print(dictionary['lastSize'])
    print(dictionary['askSize'])
    print(dictionary['ticker'])
    print(dictionary['askPrice'])
    print(dictionary['low'])
    print(dictionary['volume'])
    print(dictionary['prevClose'])
    print(dictionary['bidSize'])
    print(dictionary['lastSaleTimestamp'])
    print(dictionary['high'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Got this answered at the nearby Inland Empire Python group tonight at:

https://www.meetup.com/iepython/events/267124104/

At the suggestion of group member Netore, I altered to a for loop on the output dictionary and it worked perfectly:

:
output = requestResponse.json()

for i in output:
    print(i['last'])
:

Fun Python times.

Stuart